# hash substraction in ruby and output should be hash format?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I have the following two hashes

```
a = {"Jan-14"=>"10", "Feb-14"=>"100", "Mar-14"=>10}
b = {"Jan-14"=>"5", "Feb-14"=>"50", "Mar-14"=>0}
```

i need perform (a-b) also output should be hash format

Comment: I suggest you supply some more info: are the keys always the same in both hashes? are the numbers a mix of string and numeric? I guess with subtract, you mean subtract the numbers? Pls give an example of what you expect the output to be...

Comment: What is hash substraction (sic)? What is (a-b)?

Comment: When asking you need to show your effort toward solving the problem. Did you write code? If now, why? Did you search and not find any solutions? Then where and why didn't those help? Please read "[ask]" especially the links at the bottom, and  "[mcve]".

Answer (score 3):

If you mean subtracting values of same keys, then you can try

```
a.merge(b) {|k, o, n| (o.to_i - n.to_i).to_s}
# => {"Jan-14"=>"5", "Feb-14"=>"50", "Mar-14"=>"10"}
```

Comment: I didn't know the block form of `merge`, that is quite neat. Although when I try it in Ruby 2.1, the block is *only* called when both hashes have the same key. Remainder of the merge simply copies key/value from either `a` or `b` ignoring the block. Which means the defensive `(o || 0)` is probably not needed, and also depending on OP's needs it might not yet be a complete answer.

Comment: Is this can be done with [set](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html)?

Comment: @NeilSlater yes you are right. I checked with Ruby 1.9.3, and the defensive `|| 0` is not required. The block is only called when both hashes have the same key

Comment: Irrespective of Neil's comment, `(o || 0)` is redundant. `nil.to_i` is `0` anyway.

Comment: @jj_ o - old value, n - new value. I just gave a solution. The OP is free to choose variable name.